# How do half votes work in the DNC chair election?

Tags: united-states, election, democratic-party, dnc

The first round of the DNC chair election just passed. The [results where](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_National_Committee_chairmanship_election,_2017#Results)

> Sally Boynton Brown   12
>
> Keith Ellison 200
>
> **Jehmu Greene  0.5**
>
> Peter Peckarsky   0
>
> **Tom Perez 213.5**
>
> Sam Ronan 0

Where do those .5 votes come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Democrats Abroad get half a vote.

This [live blog by NPR states](http://www.npr.org/2017/02/25/517203708/live-blog-dnc-chair-race-to-begin-shortly-heres-what-to-expect) that:

> (For those wondering, a candidate could get half a vote because each Democrat abroad got half a vote.)

Also, in the [Democratic Party's Charter and Bylaws](http://www.demrulz.org/wp-content/files/DNC_Charter__Bylaws_9.11.2009.pdf), it's stated under Regional Caucuses that Democrats Abroad get 1/2 a vote.

Answer (score 0):

Under DNC rules, delegates from U.S. territories cast half rather than full votes.

Comment: Citation please.